# Simple Twig Logic issue

Tags: symfony, twig

I'am using following code to set selectedGallery to a defaultValue. The default Value should be galleryData's first Element.
Sadly it doesn't work. selectedGallery does not exist after the snipped run through...
Thanks for help

```
{% if selectedGallery is not defined %}
    {% for gallery in galleryData|keys|slice(0, 1) %}
        {% set selectedGallery = gallery %}
        //if i access galleryData here, it exists ?!
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

later the same file:

```
<div id="{{idPref}}PictureBox" class="backA">
    {% block pictureBox %}
        {% for picture in galleryData[selectedGallery] %}
            {{selectedGallery}}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endblock %}
```

Symfony says that the variable doesn't exists.

Comment: Does it enters the if condition or does your galleryData contain any data??? have you printed it and checked??

Comment: Thanks your question solved it somehow...
I Realized that gallery is an array itself, and i tried to use it as a string...

Comment: Well, its still not working...
I cannot access selectedGallery later in the file

Comment: @Martin could you `dump()` your variable after set it and in your `pictureBox`? Like: `{{ dump(selectedGallery) }}`

Comment: Untested, but could you try setting selectedGallery to null *before* the for loop. I vaguely remember that a for loop has its own scope in twig, but I am not sure

Comment: @ThomaK i thought so, too and have allready tested but then the variable is just to what i've set it before...

Comment: I just tested it, and for me this works

Comment: @ThomasK i just noticed that if i define it before it's not undefined anymore...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

First:

```
{% if selectedGallery is not defined %}
    {% set selectedGallery = galleryData|keys|first %}
{# ... #}
```

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/first.html

Later:

```
<div id="{{idPref}}PictureBox" class="backA">
    {% block pictureBox %}
        {% for picture in attribute(galleryData, selectedGallery) %}
            {{picture}}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endblock %}
{# ... #}
```

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/attribute.html

Comment: It was correct, but the scope of your variable was a loop, so you do not have access to that variable out of that loop:

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/set.html 

You have to declare the variables before entering the loop. I mean, as selectedGallery was not previously declared (it's not defined), it is being declared first inside the loop, so it's scoped as that loop variable.

Comment: By the way i just used the FIRST: -tip not the LATER: